# Adding values to the end of each index of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in PHP with a number of equal indices like this:

ARRAY 1 :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 17
      2 => int 145
      3 => string 'one' (length=3)
      4 => string '#3546b140' (length=9)
      5 => string '5' (length=1)
      6 => string 'ONE' (length=3)
      7 => string 'ONE' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 30
      2 => int 224
      3 => string 'two' (length=3)
      4 => string '#3546b140' (length=9)
      5 => string '6' (length=1)
      6 => string 'TWO' (length=3)
      7 => string 'TWO' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => int 3
      1 => int 31
      2 => int 120
      3 => string 'thr' (length=3)
      4 => string '#3546b140' (length=9)
      5 => string '7' (length=1)
      6 => string 'THR' (length=3)
      7 => string 'THR' (length=3)
```

This is the second array

```
array (size=3)
  1 => int 1761693
  2 => int 8911775
  3 => int 3510858
```

This would be the desired result, look at the eighth position of each index, any ideas?

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 17
      2 => int 145
      3 => string 'one' (length=3)
      4 => string '#3546b140' (length=9)
      5 => string '5' (length=1)
      6 => string 'ONE' (length=3)
      7 => string 'ONE' (length=3)
      8 => int 1761693
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 30
      2 => int 224
      3 => string 'two' (length=3)
      4 => string '#3546b140' (length=9)
      5 => string '6' (length=1)
      6 => string 'TWO' (length=3)
      7 => string 'TWO' (length=3)
      8 => int 8911775
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => int 3
      1 => int 31
      2 => int 120
      3 => string 'thr' (length=3)
      4 => string '#3546b140' (length=9)
      5 => string '7' (length=1)
      6 => string 'THR' (length=3)
      7 => string 'THR' (length=3)
      8 => int 3510858
```

I have tried to do this but it does not work!!!

```
array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

and this

```
array_push($array1, $array2);
```

Iterating with a foreach but I can't position correctly the arrays by indices, any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the first array and add the value from the second:

```
foreach ($array1 as $index => $subArray) {
    // We use $index + 1 since the first starts with 0 and the second with 1
    // We're also using $array1 since $subArray is just a copy so adding to that
    // won't change the original array
    $array1[$index][] = $array2[$index + 1];
}
```

Comment: Good answer , Initially I have a misunderstanding then I realize why you increment +1.

Good work man. 